# In UWP, what is the equivalent of DependencyType property of DependencyProperty Class of WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, dependency-properties

After migrating a WPF class library to a UWP class library, the following code is throwing an error. The [PropertyType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.propertytype?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of [DependencyProperty class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty?view=netframework-4.7.2) worked in WPF. I tried to get help from [Dependency properties overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview) of [similar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyproperty) class in UWP and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1255299/Strongly-Typed-Dependency-Property-Registration-in) online article but got a bit confused.

What I'm missing here and how can I make it work?

Code snippet [error occurs at first line of the method]:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using System.Reflection;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents;
using System.ComponentModel;
....

private static void SetPropertyValue(XmlElement xamlElement, DependencyProperty property, string stringValue)
{
    TypeConverter typeConverter TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property.PropertyType);
    try
    {
        object convertedValue = typeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(stringValue);

        if (convertedValue != null)
        {
            xamlElement.SetAttribute(property.Name, stringValue);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

**Error**:

> 'DependencyProperty' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyType' and no accessible extension method 'PropertyType' accepting a first argument of type 'DependencyProperty' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Snapshot of "ALL" the packages installed:

[image]

Comment: In short, the [System.Windows.DependencyProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netstandard-2.0&term=System.Windows.DependencyProperty) is not supported in UWP or .NetStandrad 2.0. So, you need to find other ways to set property value in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a simple example of how you can use `DependencyProperty` in UWP .

**XAML**

```
<Page x:Name="loginPage"
... >

<TextBlock Text="{Binding welcomeText,ElementName=loginPage}"></TextBlock>
```

**C#**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
...
public string welcomeText
{
     get { return (string)GetValue(welcomeTextProperty); }
     set { SetValue(welcomeTextProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for welcomeText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty welcomeTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("welcomeText", typeof(string), typeof(LoginPage), null);
```

---

In the above example we are binding the dependency property `welcomeText` which we define in the code behind (C#) to a `TextBlock`.

Please note, `ElementName=loginPage` is the page name that we define in the XAML.

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT 1:**

From what I can understand from your code you are trying to get the `PropertyType` value in order to convert it to a different type.

For this requirement you can do something like this:

In the following example we have a custom value converter which converts Length of a string to `Visibility`, in other words, return `Visibility` based on the length of string it receives for conversion, while also checking if the type of `value` provided is of the type `string`.

**XAML**

```
<Page x:Name="loginPage"
 xmlns:converters="using:projectName.converters"
... >
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:LengthToVisibilityConverter x:Key="lengthToVisibilityKey"></converters:LengthToVisibilityConverter>
</Page.Resources>
...
<TextBlock x:Name="flyoutTxt" Text="{Binding welcomeText,ElementName=loginPage}"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="Has some text" Visibility="{Binding Path=Text,ElementName=flyoutTxt,Converter={StaticResource lengthToVisibilityKey}}"></TextBlock>
```

Here, the second `TextBlock`'s visibility is based on the length of text of `flyoutTxt`.

**C#**

Custom Converter class to convert Length to Visibility :

```
class LengthToVisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {   //checking if type of "value" is String and its length
        if(value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(string) && 
           value.ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Please note, there are no changes required in the property dependency defined above.

Comment: So, how do we programmatically  get the `PropertyType` value of DependenceProperty  `welcomeText` of of your above example? Remember, the error in my code is on the following line of my code complaining that 'DependencyProperty' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyType': `TypeConverter typeConverter TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property.PropertyType);`

Comment: I probably should rephrase the post. Question is that `DependenceProperty` class in `WPF` has a property called `PropertyType`. But `DependenceProperty` class in `UWP` does not have such a property. So, how do we deal with that situation programmatically? For example, if a class `Person` in `WPF` has a property `LastName` you can access it via `Person prs = new Person(), prs.LastName`. But the `Person` class in `UWP` does not have property `LastName`. So, when we are converting the `WPF` class library to `UWP` library how do we handle Person class' `LastName` property in `UWP`?

Comment: Ok..i got it now, i misunderstood the question.. I am not sure if you will be able to replace the `PropertyType` since the `DependencyProperty` in UWP is from Windows.Ui.xaml where as in WPF it is from a different namespace.