# Binding Properties to xaml TextBox (C++/CX) UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have below property in my MainPage. And i am am trying to bind this to a TextBox in the xaml file.

```
property String^ TestProperty
{
 String^ get() { return m_testItem; };
 void set(String^ val) { m_testItem= val; }
}
```

xaml code :

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="testVal" x:Uid="testVal" Header="Laser" Text="{x:Bind TestProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I Can not see any value in the control. What am i missing here?

Comment: Look at the Output window, you may find error message that TestProperty is not resolved. Did you forget to set the DataContext object? Something like this.DataContext = this; in MainPage’s constructor.

Comment: Does this answer help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55438146/7325217

Answer (score 1):

> I Can not see any value in the control. What am i missing here?

You just declare `TestProperty` but you have not valued it. You could get `TestProperty` value in the `MainPage` construct method.

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();  
    TestProperty = "HelloW";
}
```

I found you used `Mode=TwoWay`, So you need implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. For more detail steps please refer [**data-binding-in-depth**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth)